# Full, incremental or differential backup?

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-12c, rman

Using RMAN my database is backed up once a day using a command similar to this

```
backup incremental level 1 cumulative
[...]
database
include current controlfile spfile
```

In the recovery catalog database I can see one of these backup jobs like this

```
    DB_KEY DB_NAME  SESSION_KEY COMMAND_ID              START_TIME          END_TIME            INPUT_BYTES OUTPUT_DEVICE_TYP STATUS        INPUT_TYPE    ELAPSED_SECONDS
---------- -------- ----------- ----------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------- ----------------- ------------- ------------- ---------------
   xxxxxxx dbname       xxxxxxx 2016-11-12T05:03:21     12.11.2016 05:02:28 12.11.2016 05:03:21   862159354 SBT_TAPE          COMPLETED     DB INCR                    53
```

In the table rc_backup_piece_details there are five entries with this backup job's session id

```
SESSION_KEY DB_NAME      DB_KEY     BP_KEY B INCREMENTAL_LEVEL DEVICE_TYPE          START_TIME          COMPLETION_TIME     ELAPSED_SECONDS S      BYTES
----------- -------- ---------- ---------- - ----------------- -------------------- ------------------- ------------------- --------------- - ----------
    xxxxxxx dbname      xxxxxxx    1000001 I                 1 SBT_TAPE             12.11.2016 05:03:14 14.11.2016 05:03:15               1 A     423549
    xxxxxxx dbname      xxxxxxx    1000002 I                 1 SBT_TAPE             12.11.2016 05:03:05 14.11.2016 05:03:11               6 A  862156486
    xxxxxxx dbname      xxxxxxx    1000003 D                   SBT_TAPE             12.11.2016 05:03:16 14.11.2016 05:03:17               1 A   45324586
    xxxxxxx dbname      xxxxxxx    1000004 I                 1 SBT_TAPE             12.11.2016 05:02:30 14.11.2016 05:03:01              31 A  256422458
    xxxxxxx dbname      xxxxxxx    1000005 I                 1 SBT_TAPE             12.11.2016 05:03:13 14.11.2016 05:03:14               1 A   45624595
```

As you can see, there is one backup piece wich **D** as backup type. In the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RCMRF/rcviews015.htm#RCMRF1933) I found the following:

> The type of backup. Possible values are D for data file or control file backups, I for incremental backups, and L for archived log file backups

Does this mean, that among these backup pieces there is one incremental backup of a data file or control file?

If this is the case, then I am wondering, why this only happens with this particular database. All other databases are backed up with `include current controlfile spfile` too.

The difference between this and other databases is that most other databases are backed up `incremental level=0`. So might there be the difference?

---

**Edit**: So, if backup type `D` is not incremental backup, then why is this backup piece contained in a backob job with `input_type = 'DB INCR'`? AND could  what part of the rman command triggers this datafile backup and if it is `include current controlfile spfile` then why is there a backup piece with backup type `D` for any other database?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean, that among these backup pieces there is one incremental backup of a data file or control file?

No, the Backup type is `D` means it's backup of data files or control file but it's not incremental its full backup(denoted by `NULL` for `INCREMENTAL_LEVEL`).

Other backups are differential incremental backup of the backup type `D` which is base for these incremental backups.

> The difference between this and other databases is that most other databases are backed up incremental level=0. So might there be the difference?

Incremental Level 0 and Incremental Level 1 Cumulative is different types of backup so there is difference.

> Incremental backups can be either level 0 or level 1. A level 0 incremental backup, which is the base for subsequent incremental backups, copies all blocks containing data, backing the datafile up into a backup set just as a full backup would. The only difference between a level 0 incremental backup and a full backup is that a full backup is never included in an incremental strategy.

For more: [RMAN Incremental Backups](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/bkup004.htm)

Comment: Then if backup type `D` is not incremental backup, then why is this backup piece contained in a backob job with `input_type = 'DB INCR'`? AND could you go more into detail what part of the rman command triggers this datafile backup and if it is `include current controlfile spfile` then why is there a backup piece with backup type `D` for any other database?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have an incremental backup, you must have a full backup of the datafiles against which to apply the incrementals

> A level 0 backup must exist for each data file in the BACKUP command as the base backup for an incremental strategy. Level 0 backups must not have status UNAVAILABLE. *If no level 0 backup exists, then RMAN makes a level 0 backup automatically.*

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RCMRF/rcmsynta006.htm#RCMRF107